# How build an application compatible to every resolution of android device?

Tags: android, compatibility

I wanted to create and application that can be compatible for every screen resolution of android device. How can it be done can anybody please help me?

Comment: You should probably begin by reading the relevant material provided on the Android developer's site, like [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html).

Comment: Check Android documentation -> [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). You may create different layouts for any size/density screens you want for better design adjustment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence

Use `dip` as the unit for xml elements.